# Add this Share Button not working in Private Browser

Tags: addthis

Share Button not working in private Browser and also once clear cache it not working.

My Code:

```
<div addthis:url=http://localhost:9001/#/mylist/view?mainpgm={{pro.mainprogram}}&randomid={{pro.randId}} addthis:title='Mobility search' class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook btn btn-social btn-facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
<a class="addthis_button_twitter btn btn-social btn-twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
<a class="addthis_button_google_plusone_share btn btn-social btn-google-plus" ><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
```

What's Wrong in my code?Sometimes it's working Sometimes not working

Comment: seems like it is just not working in inkognito or private browsing - 
https://addthis.desk.com/customer/portal/questions/6972753-share-buttons-not-showing-on-ipad 
I had this problem myself - I have written the devs about it.